# Merge map with array values in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Hello i have this array

`temp=[%{"a"=>1},%{"b"=>2}]`

`total=%{"c"=>3,"d"=>4}`

how do i add temp to total so i end with

`total=%{"a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3,"d"=>4}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `total` as the initial value for [Enum.reduce/3](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) and [Map.merge/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Map.html#merge/2) all of the values in your list.

```
Enum.reduce(temp, total, fn (map, acc) -> Map.merge(acc, map) end)
```

Returns:

```
%{"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "d" => 4}
```

Comment: If the keys do not conflict, and you want to just override existing keys, you could also use `Enum.map` and `Enum.into`